# How can I create event and run it every day at 00:00:00 in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, cakephp-3.0

I have an issue with my database when I do a project with cakephp and MySQL Workbench. I have a table like this:

```html
<table style="with:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>remind</th> 
    <th>status</th>
    <th>created</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>do excersice</td> 
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2017-03-04 09:56:56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>read a book</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2017-03-04 09:56:56</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want every day, all records in the database where 'DATE(created)' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days")) will auto insert at 00:00:00 new day. My table in 2017-03-05 looks like

```html
<table style="with:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>remind</th> 
    <th>status</th>
    <th>created</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>do excersice</td> 
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2017-03-04 09:56:56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>read a book</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2017-03-04 09:56:56</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>do excersice</td> 
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2017-03-05 00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>read a book</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2017-03-05 00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course, *status* field will changes to 0. I will update field in a  action other on today. Countinue, 2017-03-06 will get value from record where created = 2017-03-05.

Comment: A hint: don't use HTML for formatting postings at SO, but instead Markdown. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically running commands at a regular interval is not possible in MySQL Workbench. Usually GUI tools are not made for such background tasks, as they require an active window station (desktop or how it is named in your particular OS). What you can do however is to [create an event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) in your database and let this update your table(s).